# MySQL append new object into array of object with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to update new object into a json column in table using JSON_ARRAY_APPEND. It works when i using hard code. But when I get the data from the front end the problem occur.

> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
>     errno: 1064,
>     sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer', "Message": 'eqwe', "Time": '9:34 AM'}' AS JSON)) WHERE order_no='Orde' at line 1`,
>     sqlState: '42000',
>     index: 0,
>     sql: `UPDATE jlk_message_queue SET txn_data = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(txn_data, '$', CAST('{"MessageId": 5, "UserType": 'Customer', "Message": 'eqwe', "Time": '9:34 AM'}' AS JSON)) WHERE order_no='Order 123'`

It seems like the single quote and double quote problem. Is there any ways to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

```
customerModel.sendChatMessage = function (MessageId, UserType, Message, Time, OrderNo, result) {

    var sql = "UPDATE jlk_message_queue " +
        "SET txn_data = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(txn_data, '$', " +
        "CAST('{" + '"MessageId": ?, "UserType": ?, "Message": ?, "Time": ?' + "}' AS JSON)) " +
        "WHERE order_no=? ";

// ********Sample data which could work*********
// UPDATE jlk_message_queue
// SET txn_data = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(txn_data, '$', CAST('{"MessageId": 1, "UserType": "Doctor", "Message": "Hi, This is doctor X, May I help you?", "Time": "12:30 PM"}' AS JSON))
// WHERE order_no='Order 123'


pool.getConnection(function (err, con) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query(sql, [MessageId, UserType, Message, Time, OrderNo], function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            con.destroy();
            result(err, null);
        }
        else {
            console.log(res);

            if (res.affectedRows == 1) {
                result(null, { result: true });
            }
            else {
                result(null, { result: true, value: 'Fail to send message' });
            }

        }
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Using json in a database should be really hard thought about, is is alsoways a pain to search or manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using JSON_OBJECT the problem could be solve.

```
var sql = "UPDATE jlk_message_queue " +
    "SET txn_data = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(txn_data, '$', " +
    "JSON_OBJECT('MessageId', ?, 'UserType', ?, 'Message', ?, 'Time', ?)) " +
    "WHERE order_no=? ";
```